# scenario outilne not taking strings in examples

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, web, cucumber

in cucumber scenarios outline if you use string in examples it gives error No compatible step definition with | "AUTOMATIONPROJECT" | AutoBrandSd2503 | 2020-01-01 06:20 | systemDateTime | Project Name "AUTONEWPROJECT"\ has already been taken. |
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emHeH.png)

i expect that it should take the strings also

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When we pass data in Scenario example it is treated as string. You don't need to pass in values with quotes in examples look at the example below.

Feature file:

```
 Scenario Outline: Login 
        Given As a user I can login to my account with following credentials "<userName>" and "<Password>"
```

Step Definition:

```
  Given("As a user I can login to my account with following credentials {string} and {string}"),(userName,Password)=>{
console.log(typeof(userName)) // string
  console.log(typeof(Password)) // string
}
```